# Displaying numbers without decimal points

Tags: c#

I want to display a number in a report, however I only want to show any decimal points if they are present and the I only want to show 1 decimal space.

e.g. if the number is 12 then I want to show 12

If the number is 12.1 then I want to show 12.1

If the number is 12.11 then I want to show 12.1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had a very similar problem a while ago and the answer is to use a format string when converting the number to a string. The way to solve your issue is to use a custom numeric format string of "0.#"

```
double x = 12;
double y = 12.1;
double z = 12.11;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("0.#"));
Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("0.#"));
Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("0.#"));
```

Will give you the following output:

12

12.1

12.1

Comment: Thanks EsbenP, I should realy check I have modifed the bits I copy and pasted.

Comment: I know this is an old (and correct) answer, but the link is broken and should be removed.

Answer (score 13):

This will return a number with a single (optional) decimal place.

```
String.Format("{0:0.#}", number)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Math.Round(12.11,1)?
```

or

```
double number = 12.11;
numer.ToString("0.00")
```